# Android Studio Has Lost Ability to See My Devices

Tags: android, flutter

I've just been working on a flutter project this evening. All has been going fine, running on the emulator and my real device. All of a sudden, Android studio (3.1.1) can no longer see my emulators or physical devices, despite the fact that adb recognises them in the terminal.

The issue occurs when I edit by pubspec yaml and add

```
assets:
   - images/logo.png
```

As soon as I remove it I can see my devices again.

Does anyone have any clues as to what might be happening? I feel sure it's something stupid I've done though I literally can't think what, and the last hour of googling hasn't got me anywhere, so I need to ask for a little help.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: With the change made to pubspec.yaml, can `flutter devices` see them? Does `flutter run` work from the command line? You may need to add -d to specify a particular device. Check the indentation in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: That's got it - it's the indentation of pubspec.yaml. I hadn't twigged that it was so specific! Thank you!